# Does a GATEWAY_INTERFACE of CGI/1.1 indicate a WSGI misconfiguration?

Tags: python, apache, cgi, wsgi

I have the following lines in the config file for my Apache virtual host:

```
DocumentRoot /home/jordan/webprojects/wsgihello/web
WSGIDaemonProcess wsgihello processes=4 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP}
WSGIProcessGroup wsgihello

WSGIScriptAlias /api /home/jordan/webprojects/wsgihello/api/front.py
```

front.py just returns a text document with the keys and values of the environ dict. I noticed that `environ['GATEWAY_INTERFACE'] == 'CGI/1.1'`.

What exactly does CGI/1.1 mean? Is Apache going though CGI to start a new interpreter for each request or does it simply identify mod_wsgi by that interface identifier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an artifact of the fact that mod_wsgi calls an Apache C routine to generate the CGI key/values for the environ dictionary. Apache so happens to add that. It is not invoking a separate process.

Read:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ProcessesAndThreading

for more information about process/threading model in mod_wsgi.